# Could not create ServerSocket when starting Hive metastore

Tags: azure, hadoop, hive, azure-hdinsight

When starting Hive metastore on an HDInsight cluster (a Hadoop distribution for Microsoft Azure), I'm getting this error:

```
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:93)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.<init>(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:9083.
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:93)
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:75)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.TServerSocketKeepAlive.<init>(TServerSocketKeepAlive.java:34)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5183)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5126)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)
```

This is the command I ran:

```
hive --service metastore
```

What's the next thing you would try to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `hive --service metastore` I ran `stop_daemons` and then `start_daemons` and it seems to work every time.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use `netstat` to check port `9083`? You probably already had other service using this port number.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
ps -ef | grep hive
```

should be only one process of the hive service, in my case 2 process were running,
kill the process with pid ( `kill -9 pid` )
start hive service.